# Form of pure states on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

[Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116525/the-form-of-the-states-on-an-algebra-of-n-times-n-matrices-with-complex-entrie/1757302#1757302).

I have tried to show that pure states on $M_n(\Bbb{C})$ are of the form $\phi(A)=Tr(\rho A)$, where $\rho$ is one-rank projection.

First, as in the related question, I've shown $\phi=\phi_\rho$, where $\phi_\rho(A)=Tr(\rho A)$ and $\rho$ is a positive matrix with $Tr(\rho)=1$. Nsxt I used the fact that if $\rho$ is positive then the representation as in the answer, $\rho=\sum_{k}\lambda_kP_k$, allows us to conclude that $\|\rho\| = \sup \lambda_k$, i.e. the maximum of the eigenvalues.

But, as $B(\Bbb{C}^n)=K(\Bbb{C}^n)=C_1(\Bbb{C}^n)$, from the isometry between the dual space of the trace class and bounded operators, we know that the norm is $1$, because $\phi$ is a state and $$1=\|\phi_\rho\|=\|\rho\|=\sup\{\lambda_k\}.$$

Meanwhile, from the isometry between the dual space of $K(H)$ and $C_1(H)$ we have  $$1=\|\phi_\rho\|=\|\rho\|_1=\sum_{k}\lambda_k.$$

As the eigenvales are non-negative, the only non-zero eigenvalue is $1$ with no multiplicity, so we got $\rho$ is a one-rank projection. This can't be true, because this is the case of pure states and not states, while by the above related answer, $\rho$ is also positive. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your isometries are not such. Consider
$$
\rho_1=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&0\\0&1/2\end{bmatrix},\ \ \rho_2=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then $$\|\rho_1\|=1/2,\ \ \|\rho_2\|=1,$$ while
$$
\|\rho_1\|_1=\|\rho_2\|_1=1.\ \ 
$$

For the proof, if $\rho=\sum_k\lambda_kP_k$ with $\sum_k\lambda_k=1$ and $0\leq\lambda_k$ for all $k$ and at least two of the lambdas distinct, then the state $\text{Tr}\,(\rho\cdot)$ is a proper convex combination of states:
$$
\text{Tr}\,(\rho A)=\sum_k\lambda_k\,\text{Tr}\,(P_kA).
$$
Conversely, if $\rho$ is a rank-one projection and 
$$
\text{Tr}\,(\rho A)=t\,\text{Tr}\,(\rho_1 A)+(1-t)\,\text{Tr}\,(\rho_2 A),
$$
we have
$$
\text{Tr}\,(\rho A)=\text{Tr}\,(\,(t\rho_1+(1-t)\rho_2) A)
$$
for all $A$. It follows that 
$$
\rho=t\rho_1+(1-t)\rho_2. 
$$
So
$$
0=(1-\rho)\rho(1-\rho)=t(1-\rho)\rho_1(1-\rho)+(1-t)(1-\rho)\rho_2(1-\rho).
$$
As the two summands are positive, we get $$(1-\rho)\rho_j(1-\rho)=0,\ \ j=1,2.$$ But $\rho_j$ is positive, so $\rho_j=x_j^*x_j$, so 
$$
0=(1-\rho)x_j^*x_j(1-\rho)=[x_j(1-\rho)]^*x_j(1-\rho).
$$
Then $x_j(1-\rho)=0$, and then $\rho_j(1-\rho)=(1-\rho)\rho_j=0$. Thus,
$$
\rho_j=\rho\rho_j\rho=\lambda_j\rho,
$$
since $\rho$ is rank-one. As $\text{Tr}\,(\rho_j)=1$, it follows that $\lambda_j=1$ and $\rho_j=\rho$. So $\text{Tr}\,(\rho\,\cdot)$ is pure.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't understand why my isometries are not such.
I studied from this essay http://www.math.tamu.edu/~pskoufra/OANotes-TraceClassOperators.pdf . If I write $\rho$ as a finite sum of rank-1 projections (with multiplicity of eigenvalues) then by Lemma 6, it's op-norm is the supremum of the eigenvalues, by def5 the trace class norm is the sum. However, by lemma 22, Thm 23 and 25 the isometries are the same, with norms $||\rho||_1=||\rho||=||\phi_\rho||$, because $C_1(\Bbb{C}^n)=K(\Bbb{C}^n)=B(\Bbb{C}^n)$

Comment: The isometries you refer to give you that  $\rho\longmapsto\phi_\rho $ is isometric. It doesn't imply that  $\|\rho\|_1=\|\rho\|$, which is trivially false.

Comment: But $\rho \to \phi_\rho$ is isometry between $C_1(\Bbb{C}^n) \to K(\Bbb{C}^n)' $ thus $||\rho||_1=||\phi_\rho||$ and it is also isometry between $B(\Bbb{C}^n) \to C_1(\Bbb{C}^n)'$ so $||\phi_\rho||=||\rho||$.
I understand that I don't understand something... thank you again.

Comment: When $C_1(\mathbb C^n)$ is the dual of $K(\mathbb C^n)$, you are using the norm $$\|\phi_\rho\|=\sup\{|\text{Tr}(\rho K)|:\ \|K\|=1\}.$$ when $B(\mathbb C^n)$ is the dual of $C_1(\mathbb C^n)$, you are using the norm $$ \|\phi_\rho\|=\sup\{|\text{Tr}(\rho K):\ \|K\|_1=1\}.$$ You seem to be assuming that these two are the same; but the first one is $\|K\|_1$ and the second one is $\|K\|$.

Comment: ohhh, got it. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: I believe the last line should read: $\rho_j = \rho$ instead of $\rho_j = 1$.

Comment: Indeed.$\ \ \ $