# Pure states on subalgebras of $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ in finite dimensions.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, quantum-information

I consider only finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces.

We know that pure states on $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ are exactly the vector states or in terms on density matrices, the rank one projections.

My question is now, is there something similar to determine purity of states on subalgebras of $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, since you are in finite dimension. Any $A\subset B(H)$ is of the form $$A=\bigoplus_{j=1}^m M_{k_j}(\mathbb C).$$
It is not hard to check that every state is of the form $\varphi:x\longmapsto \operatorname{Tr}(bx)$ for some $b\in A_+$ with $\operatorname{Tr}(b)=1$ (and, thus $\|b\|\leq1$).

We have $b=\sum_{r=1}^s b_rq_r$, where $q_r$ are pairwise orthogonal rank-one projections. The above conditions on $b$ give $b_r\geq0$ for all $r$, and $\sum_r b_r=1$. If $s\geq2$, we can write $$ \varphi(x)=\sum_r b_r \operatorname{Tr}(q_rx)
$$
and we get $\varphi $ written as a convex combination of the states $x\longmapsto \operatorname{Tr}(q_rx)$. So, if $\varphi$ is pure, we have $s=1$. That is, $b$ is a rank-one projection.

In summary, the pure states of $A$ are precisely the maps $x\longmapsto \operatorname{Tr}(qx)$, where $q\in A$ is a rank-one projection.

It would remain to prove that every rank-one projection gives rise to a pure state. You can see a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1759049/22857).

Comment: Hi. I'm revisiting this atm and I have further questions. You're answer allows us to determine the pure states of $A$, but is there a way to relate these states to the pure states of $B(H)$? I was hoping there was a result that allows us to compute the pure states of $A$ directly as restrictions from states of $B(H)$. My first guess was that the pure states of $A$ where the restrictions of the pure states of $B(H)$, but this is incorrect.

Comment: It's kind of the other way around. There are pure states of $B(H)$ which are not pure when restricted to $A$. But any pure state of $A$ is a restriction of a pure state.

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering if there exists and "if and only if" statement regarding the connection between states of $A$ and states of $B(H)$?