# Pure states of $M_n(\Bbb C)$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I saw a reference book,there is a statement:the pure states of $M_n(\Bbb C)$ are the rank 1 projections of $M_n(\Bbb C)$.

By definition of states,they should be the positive linear functional of norm 1.So the pure states should be positive linear functional of $M_n(\Bbb C)$.How to interpret the statement.

Comment: As every linear functional on $M_n(\mathbb C)$ is of the form $A\mapsto\operatorname{tr}(AB)$ for some matrix $B$, states and density matrices have a one-to-one correspondence (and thus the pure states correspond exactly to rank-1 projections). For a more detailed answer, check out [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2881837/495075).

Comment: That is indeed true. Assume that $B,B'\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ generate the same state $\phi$ (via the trace). Define $A_{xy}:z\mapsto\langle x,z\rangle y$ for arbitrary $x,y\in\mathbb C^n$, then $\langle x,By\rangle=\operatorname{tr}(A_{xy}B)=\phi(A_{xy})=\operatorname{tr}(A_{xy}B')=\langle x,B'y\rangle$, so all matrix elements of $B,B'$ coincide (and thus $B=B'$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to check that any linear functional on $M_n(\mathbb C)$ is of the form $X\longmapsto \operatorname{Tr}(AX)$ for some $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$. Under this correspondence positive functional correspond with positive matrices, and so states correspond with positive matrices of trace 1. Among these, one can check that the pure states are precisely those [given by the rank-one projections](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2881837/22857).

Comment: Yes, you use the same definition: you take them to be the extreme points of the state space. The states on an operator system $S$ are exactly the same as the states on $C^*(S)$, so there is nothing new or different.